# responsive iframe center for ipad

Tags: css, iframe

hello i have problem for iframe is not responsive for ipad 
this my code css for iframe

```css
iframe {

float:center;
width: 100%;
vertical-align: middle;

max-width: 100%;



}
```

[enter link description here](http://www.swissprogress.ch/visualisation-interactive-en-3d)

Comment: not solution  please?

Comment: hello how to make iframe center responsive design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't check it on iPad, but float doesn't have center.

Try this code

css

```
iframe{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    display:block;
    float:none;
    max-width: 150px /* if you use 100% it will fill whole screen */
}
```